# Double counting in number theory!

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Recently I found in a book that double counting can be used to solve even number theory problems.But It didn't contain any such examples.In addition I could hardly imagine any scenario where such a technique can be used in number theory.

So,I would really appreciate if anyone provides any such example as an answer or provide some reference on some application.

Comment: A quick glance at Wikipedia reveals https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)#Additional_examples.  Sounds like you haven’t tried looking very far? (See last 2 examples.)

Answer (score 2):

Double counting is used to prove results related to Quadratic Gauss sums and Gauss sums. You can refer to any standard text on Modern Number theory (for example A classical Introduction to modern number theory by Kenneth Ireland and Michael Rosen) for reference.